# SQL Server : Dynamic Union Join

Tags: sql-server

I have bunch of data tables named like the following:

- db_table_2014_01
- db_table_2014_02
- db_table_2014_03
- db_table_2014_04
- ....

As you can guess, the those numbers represent year and month. Now, what I need to do is to union-all-join only the necessary database tables using stored procedure depending on the start date and end date a user requests. ie) from 2014-01-01  to 2014-03-31

Well, I could come up with this shameful way to solve it...

```
// Create a varchar variable to keep appending queries
// While start date month < end_date
// {
//    Change start_date to yymm format
//    Query += SELECT * FROM db_yymm WHERE Blah Blah
//    Query += Union All
//    start date = start date + 1 month
// }
// Delete the unnecessary last Union All
// Fire the query somehow.
```

Is is technically possible and effective way to do it? Or is there a better way for it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do it this way with dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Szymon would you mind showing me some of the codes? I'm mysql guy and totally not familar with this stored procedure stuff.. :S

Comment: @Raccoon - so, your mysql does not have stored procedures ?

Comment: @Raccoon - Try this tutorial on dynamic sql - http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/generate-dynamic-sql-statements-in-sql-server/ The concept is simple, you generate sql strings as variables and then execute it using a stored procecure like sp_execute or sp_executeSql.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Mmmmm.. i'd rather say I wasn't aware of this method at all.

Comment: @Raccoon - ..it seemed like you said that mysql does not have sp. now that would be weird :)

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Haha, sorry for giving you some confusions. I was trying to say "I'm mysql guy so that I'm not familiar with mssql syntax and its stored procedure stuff". The tutorial is really helpful btw!

Comment: Best fix here is almost certainly to fix your schema design, and put all these into one table with date field as the first part of the primary key.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That's what I really wished... but unfortunately, my client really wants to keep tables like that and I couldn't convince him no matter what.  That's why I have to do it this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are pretty much on track. This will look like this using dynamic SQL:

```
declare @startdate as date = '20140101' -- the start date should have day = 1
declare @enddate as date = '20140401' -- the end date should have day = 1

declare @date as date = @startdate

declare @sql as nvarchar(max) = N''

while @date <= @enddate
begin
    -- build the query for each month
    set @sql = @sql + N'SELECT * FROM db_table_' 
        + replace(convert(nvarchar(7), @date, 111), N'/', N'_')
        + N' UNION ALL '

    set @date = dateadd(month, 1, @date)
end

-- remove last N' UNION ALL '
if len(@sql) > 11
    set @sql = left(@sql, len(@sql) - 11)

-- execute
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks !! :D This will sure come in handy!